# In mybatis how to elegantly check parameter before execute real sql?

Tags: mybatis

For example there is a dao like this:

```
void batchInsert(List<User> userList); 
List<User> getUsersByIds(List<Long> idList); 
void deleteUsersByids(List<Long> idList);
```

If the parameter of List is empty, then will throw exception,because the sql is wrong.eg,

```
mysql> select * from tb_user where id in () ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

As a developer I don't want to care this. If the paramter is null(or empty), just return, dont't go ahead to execute the sql.

By tracking mybatis source code, I find a method.
That is modify source code of org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate. For example,
we can add the check parameter logic in selectList:

```
 public <E> List<E> selectList(String statement, Object parameter) {
  if(parameter instanceof List){
      if(((List) parameter).isEmpty()){
        List<E> result =  new ArrayList<>();
        return result;
      }
  }
return this.sqlSessionProxy.<E> selectList(statement, parameter);
```

}

and could do like so in update,delete,insert methods. But I feel this method is not good. So I'd like to know if there is some better method for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to make this solution generic at least in mybatis. The approach you suggested does not work. Consider the following `selectList` invocation:

```
selectList("SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT (id IN ())", new ArrayList())
```

With you modification it will return empty list and this is most probably now what client expects. To implement this correctly you need to parse the query and replace expressions like `column in ()` with `false` yielding expressions like `1=0`.

So that

```
select * from tb_user where id in ()
```

is transalted to

```
select * from tb_user where 1 = 0
```

And

```
select * from tb_user where NOT (id in ())
```

to

```
select * from tb_user where NOT (1 = 0)
```

But this makes implementation of designed-to-be-thin wrapper unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'll tried to do this in my app by spring AOP.